# liferay 7 date field pre populate with current date

Tags: liferay

I've created a new form in Liferay 7 and added a date field. I would like the form to pre populate with the current date when the page is loaded. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, not with the `DateDDMFormFieldType` Liferay provides.

You could of course write your own implementation based on Liferay's which could offer the possibility of choosing the User's current Date as default value or render it always (as some kind of CurrentDateDDMFormFieldType or whatever you'd like to call it).

Some links you might find useful:

- [Liferay's DateDDMFormFieldType implementation](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/7.0.x/modules/apps/forms-and-workflow/dynamic-data-mapping/dynamic-data-mapping-type-date)
- [Liferay's tutorial for implementing your own DDMFormFieldType](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-form-field-types)